# I got a rejection error from the redux toolkit while trying to update the item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, redux-toolkit

I am working on a MERN app and I have a problem when updating items. I am getting rejections when sending a patch request and there is not much info for debugging to solve the problem. I will appreciate it if someone can point out some logic that is not correct in my code. Thank you in advance.
Here below is the logic I have implemented.

**postService.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API_URL = '/api/posts/';

const updatePost = async (postId, postData, token) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };
  const response = await axios.patch(`${API_URL}/${postId}/`, postData, config);

  if (response.data) {
    return {
      ...response.data,
      id: postId,
    };
  }
};
```

**postSlice.js:**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import postService from './postService';

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  isLoading: false,
  message: '',
};

export const updatePost = createAsyncThunk(
  'posts/updatePost',
  async (id, postData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await postService.updatePost(id, postData, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response.data.message) ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);

export const postSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'post',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
.addCase(updatePost.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(updatePost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.posts = state.posts.map((post) =>
          post.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : post
        );
      })
      .addCase(updatePost.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.message = action.payload;
      })
 });
  },
});

export const selectAllPosts = (state) => state.posts.posts;
export const { reset } = postSlice.actions;
export default postSlice.reducer;
```

**Form.js:**

```
const Form = ({ postId, setPostId }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    postCreator: '',
    title: '',
    body: '',
    imageFile: '',
  });

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  const post = useSelector((state) =>
    postId ? state.posts.posts.find((post) => post._id === postId) : null
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (post) setFormData(post);
  }, [post]);

  const clearPost = () => {
    setPostId(0);
    setFormData({
      postCreator: '',
      title: '',
      body: '',
      imageFile: '',
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (
      !formData.postCreator &&
      !formData.title &&
      !formData.body &&
      !formData.imageFile
    ) {
      toast.warning(
        'Please fill out all fields, and make sure you are also logged in'
      );
    } else if (postId) {
      dispatch(updatePost(postId, formData));
      console.log(postId);
    } else {
      dispatch(createPost(formData));
      clearPost();
      setPostId(null);
    }
    clearPost();
  };
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an error you can add to your question?

Comment: The error I am getting is only the one in the screen shoot attached to this question

Comment: `console.log(error)` in the catch of `updatePost` thunk

Comment: here is the error:`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')
    at postSlice.js:73:1
    at createAsyncThunk.ts:604:1
    at step (RefreshUtils.js:264:1)
    at Object.next (RefreshUtils.js:264:1)
    at RefreshUtils.js:264:1
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __async (RefreshUtils.js:264:1)
    at createAsyncThunk.ts:582:1
    at createAsyncThunk.ts:653:1
    at index.js:16:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second param of `createAsyncThunk` is the `payloadCreator`.
The first param of the [`payloadCreator`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) is the arguments. The second param of `payloadCreator` is `thunkAPI`.

So you should combine `id` and `postData` into a single object to represent the arguments.

**Update postSlice.js:**

```
export const updatePost = createAsyncThunk(
  'posts/updatePost',
  async ({id, postData}, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
      return await postService.updatePost(id, postData, token);
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        (error.response.data.message) ||
        error.toString();
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
    }
  }
);
```

**Update where you dispatch the updatePost thunk:**

```
updatePost({
  id: 123,
  postData: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
})
```

Comment: now I am getting this error: ` PATCH http://localhost:3001/api/posts/undefined 404 (Not Found) response:
config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
data: "No post with id: undefined"
headers: {access-control-allow-headers: '*', access-control-allow-methods: '*', access-control-allow-origin: '*', connection: 'close', content-length: '26', …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"`

Comment: `id` is undefined which means you're probably not passing an object with an `id` property to the `updatePost` thunk when you are dispatching it.

Comment: I have just added the component where I dispatch the updatePost there you can see I am passing the data and the id, I also consol log it and can see the id.

Comment: Change it to `dispatch(updatePost({id: postId, formData}));`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is that when editing the item and clicking on the update button it just returns an empty item without a values.

Comment: Your initial problem has beens solved. It's time to mark this as accepted and ask a new question.